# HTML form Classes Model creation

Tags: html, ios, web-services, post

i need to create an ios app that consume a webservice , i have a web page with an html form that works with this webservice so i want to know if is possible to create a program that read the form in the web page and creates the class model in objective c for using latter in the program.

thanks in advance 
I

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you can't do that. Everything in an app has to be part of the signed bundle. This would be a security problem if code could be created and executed dynamically. You could create a class that maps to the form and use that.

Comment: ok , i am talking about "mapping the form" in a class as a entity model ,is necesary i will do by hand or there are a more proper way to do it ?

Comment: Well you don't particularly have to have an entity model as such. You can create a plain old NSObject class. Create properties that mach your web form and use this as a Model class. I think you need to read a little bit on communicating with a webservice. ASIHttp or AFNetworking are good libraries or the Apple examples are pretty good. Just creating a model class is 2% of what you need to know.